# How do I set the value of a variable in Powershell using Get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I'm trying to update Active Directory with info from a csv file generated by one of our client-facing systems.  I'm storing the info, an ID#, in the facsimileTelephoneNumber AD Attribute (don't ask why).  Here's where it's getting tricky.  If there is already a value in that attribute that is different from the one that is stored in the csv file, I don't want to change it.  I'm setting the value from the csv file to variable $ID, and trying to set the value from AD to variable $CurrentID.  From there, I'm comparing the two to see if they're equal. Importing the $ID from the csv is working fine, no problem there.  But setting the $CurrentID using Get-ADuser isn't doing what I expect it to.

```
$CurrentID = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties facsimileTelephoneNumber
```

is what I'm using to try and set that. But when I compare the 2 variables using:

```
if ($CurrentID -eq $ID) {Execute this code}
```

it always tests false, so nothing happens. When I call the variables to see what's in them, I get the correct data from $ID, but $Current ID, the one I pull using Get-ADUser, returns a whole block of attributes, DistinguishedName, Enabled, facsimileTelephoneNumber (which is the one I want), GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SAMAccountName, SID, Surname, and UserPrincipalName.  I think that's why the equal test is failing, but I don't know how to fix it.  I'm very new to Powershell scripting, so be kind.

Comment: You need the **value** of that property, not a user object with properties of which one is the one you are after, `$CurrentID = (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties facsimileTelephoneNumber).facsimileTelephoneNumber`

Comment: What kind of value is `$ID`? Is it just the new value for `facsimileTelephoneNumber`? Or does it contain several properties?

Comment: That's because you have to narrow the value at runtime or, you can compare the property using dot notation. `$CurrentID` returns an *ADObject* as you could see, and in order for you to reference a property, you can use the dot operator to do so: `$Current.facsimileTelephoneNumber`. Where is your `$username` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but $Current ID, the one I pull using Get-ADUser, returns a whole block of attributes

That's normal. [`Get-ADUser` returns an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs) with all the properties. To compare just the one property, use `$CurrentID.whatever`. For example:

```
if ($CurrentID.facsimileTelephoneNumber -eq $ID) {Execute this code}
```

If `$ID` is also an object with properties, then you might need to do the same for that:

```
if ($CurrentID.facsimileTelephoneNumber -eq $ID.facsimileTelephoneNumber) {Execute this code}
```

But I can't tell you that for sure without knowing what type of variable `$ID` is.

Comment: That was it.  I didn't understand the difference in an AD object and the individual properties contained within it.  Thanks very much for the help.